# Jquery tabs: default selection and load JSP

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using JQuery tabs and I have a problem to select & load tab content on document ready.
I have the following JSP page:

```
<script>            
        $(function() {
            $("#welcomeLink").click(function() {
                $('#welcome').load('/HomeAutomation/private/welcome');
                return true;
            });

            $("#boilerLink").click(function() {
                $('#boiler').load('/HomeAutomation/private/boiler');
                return true;
            });

            $("li").click(function() {
                $("li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });

            $("#menu").tabs();
            $("#boilerLink").trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainFrame">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul id="tabs">
                <li><div id="welcomeLink"><a href="#tab-1">Welcome</a></div></li>
                <li><div id="boilerLink"><a href="#tab-2">Boiler</a></div></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab-1"><br>
                <div id="welcome"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-2"><br>
                <div id="boiler"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I load the page, the tab 'Boiler' is well selected but his content is not loaded. 
However:

1. The function "$("#boilerLink").click(function()" is well called (tested with alert).
2. The tab works perfectly well if I click on it with the mouse cursor.
3. If I invert the both 'li' tags: it's works ! Seems like it's only possible to select the first tab.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why your code is not working, but you could try to use the built-in AJAX feature of jQuery UI.

Simply set the `href` attribute to the URL of the external content:

```
 <div class="mainFrame">
   <div id="menu">
     <ul id="tabs">
       <li><a href="/HomeAutomation/private/welcome">Welcome</a></li>
       <li><a href="/HomeAutomation/private/boiler">Boiler</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and specify that the second tab should be activated by default:

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu").tabs({
    active: 1
  });
});
```